# What is the syntax for DSE Cassandra solr_query for collection types?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I am using DSE Cassandra and wanted to use solr_query for the collection (map, list, set etc.) type columns so wanted the syntax of solr_query for this.

The sample table schema is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE user_properties ( 
   id UUID, 
   user_id INT,
   properties MAP<text, text>,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Here how do I do `solr_query` for the '`properties`' column?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the schema set up to handle this as a dynamic field.  The offical DataStax Doc is [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/srch/usingDynamicFields.html?hl=using,dynamic,fields). Once the setup is done you can follow this [doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/srch/advTutorialSearchDynamicField.html) to setup the query.